# Zend Framework HTTPS URL

Tags: zend-framework, url, routes, https

Is there any more or less standard way to specify a route that would create URL's with explicitly specified scheme?

I've tried the solution specified [here](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/model-view-controller-mvc-21/http-https-serverurl-baseurl-4136.html) but it's not excellent for me for several reasons:

1. It doesn't support base url request property. Actually rewrite router ignores it when URL scheme is specified explicitly.
2. It's needed to specify separate static route for each scheme-dependent URL (it's not possible to chain module route with hostname route because of base url is ignored).
3. It's needed to determine HTTP_HOST manually upon router initialization in bootstrap as long as request object is not present within FrontController yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a combination of the ServerUrl and Url view helpers to construct your URLs, eg (view context)

```
<?php $this->getHelper('ServerUrl')->setScheme('https') ?>
...
<a href="<?php echo $this->serverUrl($this->url(array(
    'url' => 'params'), 'route', $reset, $encode)) ?>">My Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own custom `View` helper for composing an `URL`. Take a look at the http://www.evilprofessor.co.uk/239-creating-url-in-zend-custom-view-helper/

```
<?php 

class Pro_View_Helper_LinksUrl  
    extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract  
{  
    /** 
     * Returns link category URL 
     * 
     * @param  string          $https 
     * @param  string          $module 
     * @param  string          $controller 
     * @param  string          $action 
     * @return string Url-FQDN 
     */  
    public function linksUrl($https = false, $module = 'www',  
        $controller = 'links', $action = 'index')  
    {  
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();  

        $urlParts = $router->assemble(array(  
            'module'     => $module,  
            'controller' => $controller,  
            'action'     => $action,  
        ), 'www-index');  

        $FQDN = (($https) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $urlParts;

        return $FQDN;
    }  
}
```

Comment: That is about how to rotate URL's between different hosts within CDN. The question is about how to compose URL's using existing routes but specify HTTPS scheme for some of them. Thank you.

Comment: You realise that method only returns either `https://` or `http://` and nothing else